# Ruby on Rails Test Database Not Committing New Records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, unit-testing, factory-bot

Is there a way to use Factory Girl to commit new changes to the test database in Ruby on Rails?

I have the following factory:

```
Factory.define :shipping_info do |si|
    si.name "Foo Bar"
    si.street "12 Candy Lane"
    si.country "US"
    si.zip "12345"
    si.state "IL" 
end
```

And I have the the following test:

```
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../../spec_helper'

describe CgCart::ShippingInfo do

   before(:each) do
      @order = Factory(:order)
      @order.order_line_item = Factory(:order_line_item)
      @shipping_info = Factory(:shipping_info)
   end

    it "order should not be nil" do
        @shipping_info.should_not be_nil
    end
end
```

When I run this test it passes. However, no new records are created in my test database. I need data in there for a Dameon to work with.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Using Factory.create(:order) should write that object to your database.
If you have transactional fixture set to true, all data that gets written to database gets rolled back after the tests finish.

You cant `tail -f log/test.log` before running your tests and you will see a *lot* of activity there.

I hope that clears your situation.

Comment: Did you mean you can use `tail -f` or you can not?